# Want to Display message if the array is empty in Polymerjs

Tags: polymer, polymer-1.0, web-component

Can someone please help how to make this template show if the filter is not found in the array.

```
<template is="dom-if" if="{{itemsEmpty}}">
     The array is empty!
</template>
```

here is my entire code. but for some reasons the if condition in the dom-if template is not working

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <script src='bower_components/webcomponentsjs/webcomponents-lite.min.js'></script>

 <link rel="import" href="bower_components/polymer/polymer.html">
 <link rel="import" href="bower_components/iron-image/iron-image.html">
 <!--<link rel="import" href="bower_components/iron-ajax/iron-ajax.html">-->
 <link rel="import" href="bower_components/paper-item/paper-item.html">
 <link rel="import" href="bower_components/paper-input/paper-input.html">
 <link rel="import" href="bower_components/paper-dropdown-menu/paper-dropdown-menu.html">
 <link rel="import" href="bower_components/paper-listbox/paper-listbox.html">
 <link rel="import" href="bower_components/paper-button/paper-button.html">
<style>
.taller{
  height:120px;
}
[vertical-align="top"] ul {
  margin-top: 0;
}
[vertical-align="bottom"] ul {
  margin-bottom: 0;
}
button, paper-button {
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  background-color: #eee;
  /*padding: 1em;*/
  border-radius: 3px;
  cursor: pointer;
}
button:focus {
  outline: none;
  border-color: blue;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
     <dom-module id="employee-list">
         <template>

             <paper-input value="{{filterValue}}" label="Search For a   Company" floatingLabel id="searchCompany"></paper-input>
             <paper-dropdown-menu label="Select Project Type">
                  <paper-listbox class="dropdown-content" >
                         <template is="dom-repeat" items="{{items}}" as="test" filter="{{Filter(filterValue:input)}}">
                              <paper-item value="{{test.fname}}">{{test.fname}} - {{test.lname}}</paper-item>

         </template>
     </paper-listbox>
     </paper-dropdown-menu>
     <paper-listbox >
    <template is="dom-repeat" items="{{items}}" filter="{{Filter(filterValue)}}">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-12" style="font-size:15px;font-family:'Open Sans'">
                {{item.fname}} - {{item.lname}}
            </div>
            <hr />
            <template is="dom-if" if="{{itemsEmpty}}">
              The array is empty!
          </template>    
        </div>

    </template>
</paper-listbox>
</template>
<script>
       Polymer({
       is: 'employee-list',
       properties: {
       items: {
          type: Array,
          observer: '_itemsChanged'
       },
       filterValue: {
          type: String,
          notify:true
        },
       itemsEmpty: {
          type: Boolean
        }
      },
      ready: function() {
           this.items = [{'fname': 'Jack', 'lname':'Bayo'}, {'fname': 'Skellington','lname':'Dar' }];
      },
     _itemsChanged: function(items){
            this.itemsEmpty = items.length == 0;
      },
     Filter: function (val) {
         return function (items) {
            if (!items) return false;
            if (val != null || val != undefined) {
                return (items.fname && ~items.fname.toLowerCase().indexOf(val.toLowerCase())) ||
            (items.lname && ~items.lname.toLowerCase().indexOf(val.toLowerCase()));
        }
        else
            return true;
    };
  }
});
</script>
</dom-module>
<employee-list></employee-list>
</body>
</html>
```

I will really appreciate any help here. Here is the plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/Qy6LeAfe93u4CK2G43eX?p=preview

Thank you

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I've found a number of problems with your sample:

1. The `polymer.html` import breaks your plunk (see all the errors from `registerElement`). That's because the other imports try to import Polymer from different URLs
2. The `dom-if` is inside the `dom-repeat`
3. Observing `items` won't work because the items property isn't changed when you use `filter`.

What does change is [`renderedItemCount`](https://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/api/#dom-repeat:property-renderedItemCount) property, which you can observe and use to control the `dom-if`. The property is updated whenever filter fires or `items` array changes.

To sum up:

1. Remove Polymer import
2. Move `dom-if` outside repeater
3. Add binding to `dom-repeat`: `rendered-item-count="{{renderedCount}}"`
4. Change the `if` property to use the actually rendered item count: `if="{{!renderedCount}}"`

Here's how the element's template can look:

```
<paper-input value="{{filterValue}}" label="Search For a Company" floatingLabel id="searchCompany"></paper-input>

<paper-listbox >
  <template is="dom-repeat" items="{{items}}" filter="{{Filter(filterValue)}}" rendered-item-count="{{renderedCount}}">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-sm-12" style="font-size:15px;font-family:'Open Sans'">
        {{item.fname}} - {{item.lname}}
      </div>
      <hr />   
    </div>               
  </template>

  <template is="dom-if" if="{{!renderedCount}}">
    The array is empty!
  </template> 
</paper-listbox>
```

Comment: You're very right. This is my first experience with polymer. Thank you so much, you're a genius. Works just the way i wanted it. Thank you Tomasz

Comment: If the answer was helpful, please show you appreciation by accepting it ;)

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work :)

Comment: Thanks you @Tomasz. Appreciate it

Comment: @tomasz-pluskiewicz http://plnkr.co/edit/3r1wdLFHxsVkxPudukbb?p=preview doesn't work 404, please fix or paste as code in answer.

Comment: @pejas must've deleted by accident. I pasted actual code instead

Answer (score 0):

This is untested, but I think.
`<template is="dom-if" if="{{!items}}">`
should be
`<template is="dom-if" if="{{itemsEmpty}}">`

Comment: yes i try that but it's not working. I'm thinking whether if the _itemChange function needs to be inside the filter function. I'm not sure.

Comment: Hmm, I think the problem is the filter does not change the items property, so the `_itemsChanged` observer is not called and therefore the `itemsEmpty` is not changed.

Comment: Thank you @2pha but do you any idea how to make the filter change the items property. here is the http://plnkr.co/edit/Qy6LeAfe93u4CK2G43eX?p=preview

Comment: Ok. Thanks for the help. appreciate it!

Comment: Hmm, I can't get it to work (I'm pretty new to Polymer). The [paper-listbox](https://elements.polymer-project.org/elements/paper-listbox) element has an `items` property which is the visible items. I would bind the visibility to the length of that.